# When to increase the Hidden Layers and number of features in hidden Layer If error is high in training itself?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am using the Neural Network for a classification task with (1 Hidden Layer and 10 features).

Result is not quite good. I got high error rate in training dataset itself.

What should i do now ?

1. Do I need to increase the number of nodes in Hidden Layers ? What will be the impact ?
2. Do I need to increase the number of input features to the  Hidden Layer ? What will be the impact ?

Comment: How many inputs and outputs are there in your network?  How many training samples do you have?  Are you doing any cross-validation? It is hard to give specific recommendations without knowing the details of your situation.

Comment: Inputs features are 6, Output is single which take 2 values 'YES/NO'. Right now i am not doing any cross validation... I have around 50 LAKH training sample...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current configuration of your network and not knowing more about the data set, I recommend adding a second hidden layer with only a few nodes (maybe 4).  That will allow for more variability in the types of decision surfaces generated (e.g., multiple distinct clusters for a single class).

Even though you are doing binary classification, I would also split the output into two nodes (one for true, one for false) and take the max value as your classification result.  I usually see better convergence that way and interpreting errors is a bit more intuitive.